# Display different parts of model in EditorTemplate in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When creating a form for a Store I have one ContactPerson and one EconomyPerson. For each of them I need the name to be required but the email should not even be visible in the form for the EconomyPerson.

I would like to use the EditorTemplate for my class Person. But can I hide input fields and change the validation requirements from the Store class?

```
public class Person 
{
    [Required]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public String MobileNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    [Required]
    public Person ContactPerson { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Person EconomyPerson{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Short answer - No. You need separate view models if you want separate validation requirements

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the quick answer